# Web services in java me midlet

Tags: java, web-services, java-me

I am trying to make midlet with web services (Country Details). I am not sure about how to display results, everything else seems to work fine.

Here is the code for getting input information and results (which i can't get):

```
task = new SimpleCancellableTask();                                   
        task.setExecutable(new org.netbeans.microedition.util.Executable() {
            public void execute() throws Exception {                                 

                String country = FieldCountry.getString();
                result = CWS.getCurrencyByCountry(country);

                System.out.println(result);
                getResultBox().setString(String.valueOf(result));

            }                                    
        });
```

In the run window I see it gets this information:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Name>Norway</Name>
    <CountryCode>no</CountryCode>
    <Currency>Kroner</Currency>
    <CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Name>Norway</Name>
    <CountryCode>no</CountryCode>
    <Currency>Kroner</Currency>
    <CurrencyCode>NOK</CurrencyCode>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

EDIT

I have used this code and it works fine now:

```
task = new SimpleCancellableTask();                                   
        task.setExecutable(new org.netbeans.microedition.util.Executable() {
            public void execute() throws Exception {                                 

                country CWS = new country_Stub();
                String country = FieldCountry.getString();
                String result = CWS.getCurrencyByCountry(country);

                if (list != null)
                {list = null; }

                String name = result.substring(result.indexOf("<Name>")+6, result.indexOf("</Name>"));
                String countryc = result.substring(result.indexOf("<CountryCode>")+13, result.indexOf("</CountryCode>"));
                String currency = result.substring(result.indexOf("<Currency>")+10, result.indexOf("</Currency>"));
                String currencyc = result.substring(result.indexOf("<CurrencyCode>")+14, result.indexOf("</CurrencyCode>"));
                getList().append("Country name: ", null);
                getList().append(name, null);
                getList().append("Country code: ", null);
                getList().append(countryc, null);
                getList().append("Country currency: ", null);  
                getList().append(currency, null);
                getList().append("Country currency code: ", null); 
                getList().append(currencyc, null);

            }                                    
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got the XML file.
Now you only have to use a simple XML parser to parse the XML.
There are good XML parsers available for J2ME.
You can take a look at

- [KXML](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_parse_an_XML_file_in_Java_ME_with_kXML)
- [NanoXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nanoxml-j2me/)

KXML is a good choice as there are lots of documentation available for KXML.

Comment: Well i have tried to read about parsing, it is still confusing for me. I made my program work by looking at another similar code. So I am not sure what kind of parsing I have used? Anyway I am glad it is working (code after EDIT)